# Difference in meaning between converges against and converge to

Tags: convergence-divergence, definition

Might be a silly question, but is there any difference between saying that a something (limit, series and so on) **converges to** a value and **converges against** a value?

Comment: These formulations mean exactly the same. But "converges against" seems to be not so common.

Comment: I think that the correct form is [converges to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence) : "he limit of a sequence is the value that the terms of a sequence "tend to"."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Googling around a bit, it looks like "converges against" is a term which is sometimes (rarely) used by Germans who are translating into English. It seems to be synonymous with "converges to".

It appears to have a alternative but related meaning when considering game theory, but that appears likewise to be very rare.